# Unity UI slider doesn't work when placed under another game object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

I'm making a main menu for my Android game and I ran into this bug I suppose which I can't seem to resolve.

I made the options button reveal a rect transform that shows sliders for volume control and buttons for right or left shooting button placement.

The UI buttons seem to work fine, but the sliders won't slide. If I place the sliders outside of the game object with the rect transform mask it works, and if for example during the editor play test I copy the slider inside the game object the copy also works, but then for example if I take a slider that was outside of the game object and put it under the game object during the play test it again won't work.

Has any of you encountered this issue? How can you work around that so I maintain the revealing-window effect? Thanks.

**EDIT:** I fixed it by resetting the scale values of the rect transform of the holding game object to 1. It was set to 117 while the width and height were set to values 117 times smaller than they would have otherwise. I don't know why it messes with hoe the touch is read for the sliders, but it was resolved after scaling it down to 1 and adjusting the rect width and height and the UI objects' scale back.

Comment: Well, something seems to overlay the slider and block the raycast which is used by Unity in order to hit the slider. Could e.g. be an invisible collider or something like that

Comment: @derHugo I don't see anything that should be blocking it. Even though there is a function that pushes it down when Options is opened, I removed the About button which is below the Options button and it still doesn't work. If I move the existing sliders around during play test it still doesn't work, but as I said creating a copy during the play test and leaving it in the same place DOES work.

Comment: Can you provide the screenshot of your hierarchy setup and related UI components?

Comment: @derHugo OK, I fixed it. It seems I adjusted the size of the items under the holding game object with the rect scale values, which was 117 while the rect width and height were accordingly 117 smaller then they would if the scale was 1. I don't know exactly what that translates to, perhaps the touch-reading resolution became too small?